# Error: attempt to index a nil value (upvalue 'cfg')

Tags: mysql, lua

El dinero en mi servidor FiveM VRP no aparece, y tampoco puedo comprar nada y creo que tiene que estar relacionado con esto. En mi base de datos, veo que se supone que hay que tener dinero.

```
[          script:vrp] SCRIPT ERROR: @vrp/modules/money.lua:269: attempt to index a nil value (upvalue 'cfg')
[          script:vrp] > fn (@vrp/base.lua:643)
```

money.lua:269 (265-274)

```
-- money hud
AddEventHandler("vRP:playerSpawn",function(user_id, source, first_spawn)
  if first_spawn then
    -- add money display
    vRPclient.setDiv(source,{"money",cfg.display_css,lang.money.display({vRP.formatMoney(vRP.getMoney(user_id))})})
    vRPclient.setDiv(source,{"bmoney",cfg.display_css,lang.money.bdisplay({vRP.formatMoney(vRP.getBankMoney(user_id))})})
        vRPclient.setDiv(source,{"Dogecoins",cfg.display_css,lang.money.Dogecoins({vRP.formatMoney(vRP.getDogecoins(user_id))})})
        vRPclient.setDiv(source,{"VenomCoins",cfg.display_css,lang.money.Diamante({vRP.formatMoney(vRP.getVenomCoins(user_id))})})
  end
end)
```

base.lua:643 (643-647)

```
        TriggerEvent("vRP:playerSpawn",user_id,player,first_spawn)
      SetTimeout(config.load_duration*1000, function() -- set client delay to normal delay
        Tunnel.setDestDelay(player, config.global_delay)
        vRPclient.removeProgressBar(player,{"vRP:loading"})
      end)
```

Comment: Hola @methiu, te encuentras en la comunidad de habla hispana de stackoverflow, en ella solo se aceptan preguntas en idioma español. Por favor, o bien editas la pregunta para traducirla al español y la mantienes en ésta comunidad, o bien la eliminas y la realizas en la comunidad inglesa. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa que las columnas de tu base de datos sean idénticas a las que te dice la líneas

```
AddEventHandler("vRP:playerSpawn",function(user_id, source, first_spawn)
```